# Executing PL/SQL Procedure with UTL_FILE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have following procedure:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sal_status(
  p_dir IN VARCHAR2, p_filename IN VARCHAR2) IS
  f_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  f_file:= UTL_FILE.FOPEN (p_dir, p_filename, 'W');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(f_file, 'REPORT: GENERATED ON ' || SYSDATE);
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (f_file);

  EXCEPTION
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_FILEHANDLE THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Invalid File.');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.WRITE_ERROR THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, 'Unable to write to file');


END sal_status;
```

This procedure compiled successfully, but when I try run/execute it:

```
BEGIN
  sal_status('UTL_FILE', 'test.txt');
END;
```

I have following errors:

```
Ora-29280: invalid directory path
Ora-06512: at SYS.UTL_FILE, line 41
Ora-06512: at SYS.UTL_FILE, line 478
ORA-06512: at HR.SAL_STATUS, line 5
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: directory created by the following way: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY p_dir AS 'C:\Users\Beibut\Desktop\Test';

GRANT READ, WRITE ON directory p_dir TO public;

Comment: What are oracle version you got

Comment: Your directory object has a wrong name `p_dir`. Instead the name should be `UTL_FILE`. However I don't recommend using names of existing schema objects even they are different types. It migh tor might not work. Instead create directory object `MY_TEST_DIR`.

Answer (score 3):

As you may see in UTL_FILE documentation for FOPEN function:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003526
You need to create directory object
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm
`CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY UTL_FILE AS 'directory/path'`
 
and grant read permission on this directory to your user
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#i2125999
`GRANT READ ON UTL_FILE TO [your_user]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone,

Correct variant provided below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sal_status(
  p_dir IN VARCHAR2, p_filename IN VARCHAR2) IS
  f_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  f_file:= UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('P_DIR', 'test.txt', 'W');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(f_file, 'REPORT: GENERATED ON ' || SYSDATE);
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (f_file);

  EXCEPTION
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_FILEHANDLE THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Invalid File.');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.WRITE_ERROR THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, 'Unable to write to file');
END sal_status;

BEGIN
  sal_status('P_DIR', 'test.txt');
END;
```